# Jquery - Calling 3rd tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to activate a third party tag on my website when a webpage show the message "Choisissez la finition"

the div which show this message is

`<div id="vw_dbs_ihdcc_TrimSelector" class="container containerColQuarter"><h2>Choisissez la finition</h2>`

I've tried something like that

```
function (session, cb){window.addEventListener("hashchange", function()
{
    if(document.location.hash.indexOf("carimage") > -1)
    {
        var len2 = jQuery("h2:contains('Choisissez la finition')").length;
            if (len2 > 0)
            {
                cb();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any advice, help ?

Many thanks,

Comment: And when is the function executed? It neither has a name, not any params are passed!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the following.

```
function doSomething(session, cb){

    if(location.hash.indexOf("carimage") > -1) {
        var len = $("h2:contains('Choisissez la finition')").length;
        if (len) {
            cb();
        }
    }
});

//Define your callback function
function mycb() {
    alert ("I am a callback function");   
}

//Bing event on hashchange using jQuery as you anyway have it.
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
    //Call your function with params
    doSomething("yourSession", mycb);
});
```